# Why getAttribute does not return option field name?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this React code in return:

I would fetch and store `key` value on option, when `select` is changing.

```js
<select
  className={"select_1"}
  onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    let startPaymentIn2 = { ...startPaymentIn };
    var selectedIndex = event.target.options.selectedIndex;
    startPaymentIn2["pricingOptionId"] = event.target.options[
      selectedIndex
    ].getAttribute("key");
    setStartPaymentIn(startPaymentIn2);
  }}
>
  {Object.entries(buyTicketData?.pricingOptions).map(([key, value]) => (
    <option key={key}>{value.name}</option>
  ))}
</select>;
```

For some reason `getAttribute("key");` return null, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`key` is a React prop that doesn’t get passed through to the DOM. It’s not on the rendered element.

Comment: and what would you suggest to get the key? add to DOM?

Comment: You shouldn’t be querying the DOM to get the option value. Get it from the event. But if you insist, use a value attribute.